# Finding the index of k. set bit in an uint64_t array of length 4

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, auto-vectorization

Im trying to index of `k`. set bit in a 256 bit integer. Here is my attempt.

```c
uint16_t find_index(const uint64_t A[4], uint8_t k) {
    uint16_t res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (k / 64) - 1; i++) {
        res += __builtin_popcountll(A[i]);
    }
  
    for (int i = 0; i < k % 64; i++) {
        res += (A[k / 64] >> ((uint64_t)i)) & 0x01;
    }

    return res;
}
```

For starters, I don't like the second loop. Im pretty sure there is a way to do it it with `clz`, `bfs` etc. but I couldn't figure out.
Secondly I'd like to make use of `sse`, `avx` instructions and autovectorization. I don't particularly care about portability and ok with using gcc/clang/linux specific extensions.

Comment: Replace the second loop with `int t = 64 - k%64; if (t < 64) res += __builtin_popcountll(A[k/64] << t >> t);`. In other words, just count the bits below bit k%64, and do that by removing the high bits (which is what `<< t >> t` does) and counting the remaining bits. `if (t < 64)` is needed for the case where k%64 is zero, since shifting a `uint64_t` by 64 bits has undefined behavior.

Comment: thanks a lot! so simple and elegant.